# Need to receive array string from WCF WebService in Android & display in ListView

Tags: android, wcf, web-services, crud

I really need your help in WCF Web service & android.
WCF web service example:

```
    public String[] checkLogin(string userName, string password)
    {
        string[] result;
        result = new string[] { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four" };
        return result;
    }
```

I need to populate this String array value in a `ListView` (android site).
Anybody have any example?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

ListView with arrray

```
  [1]: http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429
  [2]: http://android.vexedlogic.com/2011/04/02/android-lists-listactivity-and-listview-ii-%E2%80%93-custom-adapter-and-list-item-view/
```